# Extending google map api classes (or making wrappers)

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Basically, I wanted to add a few custom methods to google.maps.Map and Rectangle classes.
I could not do it, so I decided to make wrapper classes, but I ran into one problem

```
function MyClass() {

  this.redraw_map = function() {draw something};
  this.current_map = new google.maps.Map();  

  google.maps.event.addListener(this.current_map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    redraw_map();
  });
}
```

My redraw_map() method is not seen in the event handling function, unless I put the redraw method outside MyClass.
I have in plans to switch to more advanced way writing JS apps like Backbone, but first I need to understand how to overcome such problems.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the callback function that you're passing to addListener does not have a function defined redraw_map() in its current scope. A workaround is to keep a reference to your MyClass scope outside of your callback, allowing you to call it from inside the callback.

This will fix your problem:

```
function MyClass() {

    this.redraw_map = function() {draw something};
    this.current_map = new google.maps.Map();  

    // Reference to current scope
    var self = this;

    google.maps.event.addListener(this.current_map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
        // This will call the function that you defined in your scope above
        self.redraw_map();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I swithced to writing my code in CoffeeScript and understood how ".this" works and how pass it when binding functions.